# How do I find the local minima of a function from $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the way to find the local minima of a function is to find all $x$'s such that $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$. Notice that finding the second derivative is not optional; you need to compute the second derivative in order to determine if it is a minimum. EDIT: This test doesn't work for $f(x) = x^4$. Nevermind

What is the step-by-step procedure for finding all local minima of a function $g : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It’s similar, except you use the gradient and Hessian.

Comment: @amd that helps, but what about cases like f(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 where the hessian is not positive definite?

Comment: What would you do in the equivalent single-variable case? Examine higher-order derivatives until you get something that doesn’t vanish—that corresponds to the leading term of the Taylor series at the critical point. For a multivariable function, you’ll be looking at higher-rank tensors, which do get tricky to interpret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the gradient and then solve for it equal to 0. You can compute the hessian to determine it is local min or max. If you are interested in the **global** min, usually I just compare the values, which might be quicker in case of high dimension...

Simple case $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, the gradient is $(2x,2y,2z)'$, solve for it to zero yields x=y=z=0.

To see how the property of Hessian informs min/max/saddle, this post already has very nice explanations [Why/How does the determinant of the Hessian matrix, combined with the 2nd derivatives, tell us max., min., saddle points? Reasoning behind it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985889/why-how-does-the-determinant-of-the-hessian-matrix-combined-with-the-2nd-deriva)

Comment: Comparing the values is useless for local minimizers; a local max in one place might have a smaller value than a local min in another. It works for finding a global minimizer if you have reason to believe that one exists.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, yeah I want to mean the global values. I will revise.